# Visual Studio Code files and folders do not automatically sync on disk

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I create new files and folders in VSC, or when I modify files and folders in VSC, changes are not reflected on the disk.

There has to be some setting where work done in VSC will be synced with the filed and folders on the disk.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Cosmin

Comment: Did you try to save the file in VS Code? What did it say? Are you maybe trying to write to a read-only file system? Or are you running VS Code in a Docker container and are you restarting that container? Are you sure you're looking in the right place in the file system? When you quit and restart VS, is your code still there? You need to provide a lot more details for people to help you. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be due to the "GitHub Pull Requests and Issues" extension. When I disable it, this problem seems to go away.

Open your Extensions sidebar, search for `@installed git`, right click on "GitHub Pull Requests and Issues", and click "Disable", then restart VS Code. Hopefully it works for you, too.

Test it by changing a file and opening it in a plaintext editor to verify the file on the filesystem has changed.

[image]

---

If you don't want to disable the Github extension, you can click the Syncronize Changes button in the bottom bar to sync your changes to the filesystem. I'm not sure what else this does, as I don't use the Github extension for version control, I use a third party client (GitKraken)

[image]

Very annoying "feature".